# How I can simulate response variable from a model already fitted?

Tags: r, simulation, jags

I already fitted a regression model with JAGS

```
model{
    for(i in 1:n) {
        y[i] ~ dbeta(alpha[i], beta[i])
        alpha[i] <- mu[i] * phi[i]
        beta[i]  <- (1 - mu[i]) * phi[i]
        log(phi[i]) <- -inprod(X2[i, ], delta[])
        cloglog(mu[i]) <- inprod(X1[i, ], B[])
    }

    for (j in 1:p){
        B[j] ~ dnorm(0, .001)
    }

    for(k in 1:s){
        delta[k] ~ dnorm(0, .001)
    }
}
```

But I need to simulate 50 samples of response variable where each one have size, to do some plots. How can I do it?

I found this thread a litle help [Estimating unknown response variable in JAGS - unsupervised learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28533934/estimating-unknown-response-variable-in-jags-unsupervised-learning)

Should I run the chain again given the values of posterior estimates that I already have as inits?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your data are `y`, `X1` and `X2`.
You can add the 50 lines of data in your `X1` and `X2` covariates, and add 50 `NA` values in `y`. And modify `n` to include the 50 values.
Your model will then produce predictions for the 50 `NA` values for `y` added.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do exactly as you described, as long as you first create a new dataset with 50 observations and the variables `Y`, `X1`, and `X2` as described by StatnMap (*viz.*, 50 values for both `X1` and `X2` and 50 `NA`s for `Y`), but you will not need to rerun your model, as implied by StatnMap.  Just to be clear: you *can*, but you do not *need*.